# Lenovo E570: left Ctrl button is no longer located at the bottom-left corner of the keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, lenovo-laptop

I have recently got myself a new Lenovo E570 with Windows 10 on board.

As it turns out, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button have been "swapped" (in comparison with the keyboard layout on older versions of Lenovo).

So the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button is now located at the at the bottom-left corner of the keyboard, while the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is located next to it, much closer to letter keys which are typically used in conjunction with it for various common functionalities (copy, paste, cut, back, forth, etc).

As a result, many of my shortcut habits are now "deprecated".

Whenever I try to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + some letter, I get <kbd>Fn</kbd> + that letter instead.

This is extremely annoying.

I was able to deactivate the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button by pressing it simultaneously with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> button (which is also labeled <kbd>FnLock</kbd>).

That helps a bit (the 'F' buttons attain their original functionalities).

But I'm still annoyed with not having the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button where I instinctively expect it to be.

Is there any way to change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button to behave the same as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Lenovo site, this can be done in the BIOS:

1. Restart the computer
2. Enter system BIOS: Press F1 at Lenovo or ThinkPad logo during bootup.
3. Go to Config -> keyboard/mouse -> Fn and Ctrl Key swap

For Windows 10 laptop, You can also access the BIOS by holding shift while restarting.

https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht074187